# Can't figure out why data structure getting modified in Python

Tags: python

For a homework assignment, I was going through various tests and can't figure something out for the following code:

```
grammar = [ 
    ("exp", ["exp", "+", "exp"]),
    ("exp", ["exp", "-", "exp"]),
    ("exp", ["(", "exp", ")"]),
    ("exp", ["num"]),
    ]


def expand(tokens, grammar):
    result = []
    for pos in range(len(tokens)):
        print "pos = " + str(pos)
        rulec = 0
        for rule in grammar:
            # hmmmm
            print "rule = " + str(rule)
            if tokens[pos] == rule[0]:
                print "token matches rule!"
                if pos == 0:
                    for i in range(1,len(rule)):
                        result.append(rule[i])
                else:
                   for i in range(1,len(rule)):
                        result[rulec].extend(rule[i])                
            else:
                print "token doesn't match rule"
                if pos == 0:
                    print "First instance"
                    result.append([tokens[pos]])
                else:
                    print "Appending..."
                    #result[rulec].extend(copy.copy(tokens[pos]))
                    result[rulec].extend('abc')
            print "result so far = " + str(result)
            print "grammar so far = " + str(grammar)
            rulec += 1
    print "result = " + str(result)
    for i in result:
        yield i

depth = 1
utterances = [["exp","a","exp"]]
for x in range(depth):
    for sentence in utterances:
        utterances = utterances + [ i for i in expand(sentence, grammar)]

for sentence in utterances:
    print sentence
```

If I execute the above, I would expect to get this:

```
['exp', 'a', 'exp']
['exp', '+', 'exp', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'exp', '+', 'exp']
['exp', '-', 'exp', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'exp', '-', 'exp']
['(', 'exp', ')', 'a', 'b', 'c', '(', 'exp', ')']
['num', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'num']
```

However, I actually get this:

```
['exp', 'a', 'exp']
['exp', '+', 'exp', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'exp', '+', 'exp', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['exp', '-', 'exp', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'exp', '-', 'exp', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['(', 'exp', ')', 'a', 'b', 'c', '(', 'exp', ')', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['num', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'num', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

For some reason I can't comprehend, when I pass a plain string (for example, 'a') between 'exp' as in [["exp","a","exp"]], the string gets added to the end.  I put a bunch of print statements in and it appears that once pos==1 and the code appends to the result list, it also appends to the grammar list.  However, for the life of me I can't figure out why.  I don't see the connection.

If this helps, when I run the code - it appears the problem is here:

```
pos = 1
rule = ('exp', ['exp', '+', 'exp'])
token doesn't match rule
Appending...
result so far = [['exp', '+', 'exp', 'a'], ['exp', '-', 'exp'], ['(', 'exp', ')'], ['num']]
grammar so far = [('exp', ['exp', '+', 'exp', 'a']), ('exp', ['exp', '-', 'exp']), ('exp', ['(', 'exp', ')']), ('exp', ['num'])]
```

1. Issue #1 - result shouldn't have the extra 'a' at the end of the
   first embedded list
2. Issue #2 - why is grammar being modified?

What am I missing?
--Jim

Comment: I think I've answered both of those questions -- did you not see the answer I provided, or did it not make sense?

Comment: Yes you did (answer both questions) - this is in response to the answer from css to make sure I was clearly stating the problem.  However, you answered before I submitted this clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    for i in range(1,len(rule)):
        result.append(rule[i])
else:
    for i in range(1,len(rule)):
        result[rulec].extend(rule[i])
```

And here:

```
result[rulec].extend('abc')
```

You are appending a list to result, and then altering that list later by adding 'abc'. The problem is that you are not just extending the list contained in `results`; you are also doing the same thing to the list in `grammar`. You can use slice notation to append a copy of the list instead:

```
    for i in range(1,len(rule)):
        result.append(rule[i][:])
else:
    for i in range(1,len(rule)):
        result[rulec].extend(rule[i][:])
```

Comment: Sweet - that's it!  Thanks Amy - I thought it was something like that but I couldn't figure it out.  I was unaware you could use slicing like that - thanks for the tip.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're iterating over utterances and appending to it at the same time. Try something like this:

```
sentences = []
for x in range(depth):
  for sentence in utterances:
    sentences = sentences + [ i for i in expand(sentence, grammar)]

for sentence in sentences:
  print sentence
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  When I try this thought - I still get the same result/have the same problem.